Что на самом деле хранится в SerializedProperty.boxedValue?
Продолжаю работу над окнами диалогов CustomEditorWindow. Диалоги содержат все необходимые публичные поля, далее в OnGui само окно сериализуется в SerializedObject, который выводится при помощи PropertyDrawer и EditorGuiLayout в окошке. Вот как-то так:
public void OnGUI()
{
  so = new SerializedObject(this);
  GUILayout.BeginVertical();
  {
    so.Update();
    EditorGUILayout.LabelField(EditorWindow.focusedWindow.ToString());
    EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Данные для сравнения");
    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(so.FindProperty("arg1"));
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(arg1?.ToString()) && compareType == SearchCondition.CompareType.None)
      compareType = arg1.notVal ? SearchCondition.CompareType.NotExist : SearchCondition.CompareType.Exist;
    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(so.FindProperty("compareType"), GUIContent.none);
    var argProp = so.FindProperty("arg2");
    if (argProp != null)
      EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(argProp);

    so?.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
    {
      if (GUILayout.Button("Установить"))
        SetValue();
      if (GUILayout.Button("Отмена"))
        this.Close();
    }
    EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
  }
  GUILayout.EndVertical();
}

Возникла потребность при формировании диалога инициировать его ссылкой на компонент. Для этого добавил атрибут в котором передается название поля или метода откуда следует извлекать ссылку.
Объекты arg1 и arg2, это простой класс в основном состоящий из value значений. Но для того чтобы их настроить написан свой PropertyDrawer, который открывает диалог, а диалог должен быть инициирован ссылкой на компонент в качестве входящего параметра. Эта ссылка устанавливается в arg вручную до отрисовки, а arg по задумке должен ее извлекать перед созданием диалога и в редакторе создав диалог инициировать его.
С какой проблемой столкнулся. Если ссылка хранится в serializedObject, то мы спокойно ее получаем через parentProperty.serializedObject.targetObject. Но беда в том, что когда PropertyDrawer для arg1 пытается получить внутри себя ссылку из своего свойства Result, то на выходе получается null.
По факту получается в что в Window лежит ArgData, а внутри ArgData есть публичное свойство Result. В отладчике я вижу в SerializedObject.targetObject.arg1.Result, что это свойство заполнено. Но если я получаю serializedProperty для arg1 и пытаюсь через Reflection извлечь ArgData из boxedValue, то вижу в дебагере что все поля со ссылками null, а значимые заданы. При этом у сериализованного свойства arg1 ссылка SerializedObject.targetObject ссылается на окно и если дальше от него спускаться и проверить то Result содержит требуемую ссылку.
Пока вижу только один вариант. Парсить путь для serializedProperty.propertyPath и от SerializedObject.targetObject через Reflection получать значение на всю глубину serializedProperty.depth. Будут заморочки со списками поскольку propertyPath в формате Unity (типа такого args.Array.data[1].pathVal), но вроде все решаемо.
Может я как всегда все усложняю и есть более простой и правильный способ?

Как я уже писал ранее, если ты создаёшь SerializedObject сам, это значит, что ты делаешь какую то херню и приводит это к какой-то херне. В документации даже не описан его конструктора, как бы намекая что для тебя, его НЕ СУЩЕСТВУЕТ! Ты лезешь в работу редактора, творя дичь и удивляешься, что от твоего SerializedObject, получаются пустые SerializedProperty.
Диалоговое окно это окошко с текстом и кнопками да/нет, никаких ссылок он не принимает. Что ты называешь диалогом, одному тебе известно.

Что мы должны увидеть в этом OnGUI? Груду лейаутов и монструозный if? А this это ваще чё? Это некий ArgData... а он чьи будет, от кого наследуется?
Почему в вертикали ты используешь GUILayout а в горизонтали EditorGUILayout? Грязь! IMGUI без пяти минут legacy и нужно переходить на Toolkit!

Существует один единственный способ отрисовки UnityEngine.Object и это Editor, который наследуется от ScriptableObject. Об этом чёрным по английски написано в документации, в первом же предложении:

Derive from this base class to CREATE a custom INSPECTOR OR EDITOR FOR your custom OBJECT.

Всё что требуется, это передать этот объект как target. То есть не нужно создавать никаких ScriptableObject и SerializedObject и заниматься самодеятельностью, все инструменты уже есть и процедуры написаны, какими они должны быть, без ошибок.
А PropertyDrawer используется для остальных сериализуемых типов, например struct. Такого объекта как ScriptableObject там существовать не должно ВООБЩЕ!, от слова "СОВСЕМ", ни в каком виде, на расстоянии пушечного выстрела, что можно заметить по документации. Он работает только SerializedProperty, полученным через аргумент в OnGUI или CreatePropertyGUI и всё.

Пытаешься из arg1 получить ArgData, который является обладателем поля arg1? Проворачиваем фарш обратно? Не понимая что творишь полную херню? Что бы что? Почему нельзя просто передать ArgData целиком? как target в новый Editor?


Может я как всегда все усложняю и есть более простой и правильный способ?

ДА! Максимально ужасным образом!
Лень всему голова, но в итоге потратишь больше времени и нервов пожиная последствия. Прошло почти 2 месяца, а ты как мышь из анекдота: плачет, колется, но продолжает упорно есть кактус.

Так по порядку. Я не работаю с объектами в сцене, поэтому не пытаюсь перешагнуть через систему. Единственное что мне бывает необходимо получить ссылку на объект в сцене чтобы относительно него выполнять поиск в будущем. Сейчас я занимаюсь тем что делаю инструмент для настройки поиска требуемого свойства с учетом иерархии от здаанного объекта.
SerializedObject используется для сериализации любых UnityEngine.Object, я его использую исключительно для того чтобы было проще собирать интерфейс при помощи PropertyDrawer, которые на входе требуют SerializedProperty.

SerializedProperty - читаем в документаци: Use this to create custom drawers for your own Serializable classes or for script variables with custom PropertyAttributes.
Вот ArgData у меня сериализуемый класс, а все поля в моих кастомных окнах это поля. Что не так? все это работает с данными, не касаясь сцен, вмешательство в игровой процесс, исключительно для настроек.

Метод OnGui из окошка EditorWindow с диалогом которое определяет условие. Привел просто как пример.  Оно максимально упрощено. Состоит из трех секций: первый аргумент условия + операнд логического сравнения + второй аргумент условия. ArgData это как раза набор данных описывающих аргументы, те самые arg1 и arg2. Для ArgData свой PropertyDrawer, который рисует в строку три значения: No + тип аргумента + значение аргумента. А аргументы могут быть разные от значений логическое, число, строка и т.п., до сложных вроде вложенного условия, вложенного поиска для получения результата.

с Toolkit не знал, давно юнити не занимался, гляну что за зверюга)

'Существует один единственный способ отрисовки UnityEngine.' - блин я и не пытаюсь отрисовать UnityEngine.Object. Ярослав ты крайне агрессивен в навязывании своего мнения). Я делаю инструмент для формирования строки поиска в сцене, выбора компонента и нахождения у него свойства для получения значения. Да, может быть и было бы правильно сделать отдельно модель данных, цеплять ее в окне и от нее формировать интерфейс. Но мне проще схитрить и дать редактору самому себя формировать, чем ручками прорисовывать каждое поле, настраивать видимость и пр.

У меня большая коллекция самописных PropertyDrawer, они меня избавляют от массы писанины при формирования окошек, чем я и пользуюсь. Им нужны SerializedProperty, ну я поместил модель в EditorWindow и тем самым получил возможность видеть поля модели в качестве PropertyDrawer. Может это и не очень по ковбойски, но так  гораздо проще добавить в окошко текстовое поле с кнопочкой для выбора из списка имен доступных классов.

'Пытаешься из arg1 получить ArgData, который является обладателем поля arg1? Проворачиваем фарш обратно?' - arg1 это и есть экземпляр ArgData. Почему все так сложно? Попытаюсь объяснить. строка поиска у меня по задумке содержит условия, чтобы фильтровать поиск. При этом в самом условии может быть еще вложенный поиск, в котором могут быть свои условия. Для того чтобы работал поиск, ему нужна отправная точка, некий компонент в сцене. Но это вовсе не значит что сама строка поиска к нему привязана, можно искать и от другого компонента. Также и с условием, мы сравниваем входящий результат с чем-то

поскольку внутри фильтра с условиями может быть свой поиск, то ему тоже необходима ссылка на компонент, от которого осуществлять поиск. Получается что вложенные условия зависят от родительского поиска. И зависимость не всегда взял у родителя и все. Так если условие с фильтром на этапе поиска объекта в иерархии, то в качестве входящих данных для условия будет объект, если на уровне поиска компонента, то там в условия передается найденный компонент, а если на уровне значений то там объект. Знаю запутанно, но уже написано и уже работает основная масса поиска.

Не хочется писать строку запроса ручками, поэтому я заморочился с диалогами для ввода запроса поиска. Надо тебе задать поиск по иерархии, ты указываешь алгоритм поиска, диапазоны, фильтры в секции поиск по иерархии. Для секции компоненты указываешь какой тип компонента тебя интересует, опять же диапазоны и фильтры. Ну и последняя секция ты указываешь  какие значения надо извлечь с теми же диапазонами и фильтрами.

Зачем мне все это нужно? я хочу в игре иметь возможность прописать проверку, например такую, выполнить уменьшение количества входящего урона если есть родительский объект с компонентой Armor. У этого компонента получить параметр на сколько снизить урон.  Условие для поиска и извлечения значения будет задано короткой строкой текста без написания кода, а скрипт ее использующий короткий и универсальный для использования как у игрока, так и у врагов.

А по поводу диалогов, ну извиняюсь что ввел в заблуждение. Я не имел ввиду стандартные диалоги, я все мои окна EditorWindow для настройки запроса так величаю по привычке, поскольку это диалоги для настройки механизма.

If используются чтобы не рисовать лишнее или обновлять данные в модели как реакцию на поведение пользователя. Например ArgData как я писал выше рисует три поля: No+ Тип аргумента + значение аргумента. Здесь ничего хитрого не выдумывал, как реализовано в большинстве мест редактора в классе поля noValue, typeArgument и дальше поля для boolValut, stringValue, intValue, pathValue и т.п. То есть PropertyDrawer для этого класса выводит в строку первые две переменные а последней рисует одно из полей в зависимости от выбранного типа аргумента. Все просто

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedObject.html - вот пожалуйста здесь есть примеры с подобным применением сериализации для взаимодействия с объектами, так что ничего криминального в своей реализации я не вижу

Да возможно я делаю все неправильно как вы говорите, но по факту я уже реализовал решение. Зачем тут спрашиваю? Ну не потому что колется, а чтобы понять, может я чего-то просто не нашел в документации и поисках потому что сформулировать запрос не получается в своей голове до конца. Мне такие обсуждения дают толчок для дальнейшего движения, чем я и пользуюсь
